# Bitmap() is not public

Tags: java, bitmap

The problem is simple.

`public Bitmap bm = new Bitmap()`

The following code throws error saying *Bitmap() is not public in Bitmap; cannot be accessed from outside package*. The thing is that it is public (android.graphics):

`public final class Bitmap implements Parcelable { .. }`

I googled a lot and all kinds of such question come to problem when this class (Bitmap, in my case) wasn't set public. I don't get what's wrong. Is it because Bitmap class is final? Then how should i declare a variable of Bitmap type?

Any tip would be appreciated.

Already tried cleaning and rebuilding project.

Comment: I guess not: `import android.graphics.Bitmap`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not because it's final, it's because its *constructor* is marked `private`.  Judging from the documentation, you are intended to create a `Bitmap` from the `createBitmap` static methods.

Comment: so if i get it right, the only way to initialize new bitmap is through private constructor `Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)`, where i necessarily have to specify exact size of image (w, h)?

Comment: That's not a private constructor, it's a static factory method, but yes.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, the Bitmap class has a private constructor and you can create a new instance of the class using for example static methods Like

```
public static Bitmap createBitmap (DisplayMetrics display, int[] colors, int width, int height, Bitmap.Config config)
```

take a look to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) and check which one is the best for you...